# How to avoid repeated processing of Maven dependencies?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am adding a new program file to an existing Maven project. This project has a lot of dependencies and I have been using the following command in order to create a single fat `jar` file:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

However, the above command is taking very long time to run. What is the best way to reduce the build time? Perhaps it is possible to reduce the build time by building the dependencies (and also the unchanged program files) once for all, instead of doing it every time I compile the new program file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't just removing the `clean` help? It's been a while since I touched Maven, but cleaning should clean all the modules in a project. (Assuming that's what you mean by "dependencies.")

Comment: You should bind the assembly plugin to the life cycle and with that you can do this by simply using `mvn clean package`...